# Press alt + arrow to skip full line? (Or is there an existing shortcut already..? )

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am still a fresh Ubuntu user, and I switched from a Mac. What I can do on Mac, is I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> to jump one word forward or backward, or if I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>, I am able to jump to the start or end of the line. And that's what I would like to do in Ubuntu. I would assign it to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is already used to skip words.

I use that function a lot when coding, I like to keep my hands on the keyboard and just not touch the mouse at all, and it just saves me time for not having to hold the arrow key until I get to the end of the line (or the skip-a-word combo for that matter), or grabbing the mouse to click at the end, just to add a semicolon or something like that. It's not a huge deal, but that's just what I'm used to. I still keep my Mac partition for incompatibility issues, but I prefer Ubuntu over Mac.

If there is already a shortcut to do that, I'd gladly go ahead and try getting comfortable using it, but if it is not, how could I achieve what I described above, if of course it is even possible?

Comment: I ended up setting up keyboard shortcuts in the code editor itself. Most IDEs/code editors (in my experience) allow setting custom hotkeys for skipping words/lines (and selecting them). This may not be very helpful if you want it system-wide, but for me it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of questions like this from MAC users but the sad truth is that you can not do it in Ubuntu.

The only way is to use **AutoKey** (see my question):

[How to bind Ctrl+arrows to Home and End keys? xmodmap does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251479/how-to-bind-ctrlarrows-to-home-and-end-keys-xmodmap-does-not-work)

but this method is barely usable because it is damn slow and you still won't be able to use combinations for selecting like <kbd>ctrl(alt)</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>