# Change Caps Lock to Left Shift+Ctrl in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, capslock

I want that pressing <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> behave the same as pressing <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> within Xubuntu. I use these two a lot as modifiers in conjunction with other keys. The only things I find are switching Caps Lock with other keys, such as escape, ctrl or disable the key altogether.

Comment: Would remapping to hyper or some other nth level modifier be sufficient?

Comment: @xiota I don't know what you mean and how that would solve my issue.

Comment: What do you use ctrl+shift for? If you are able to reassign the shortcuts, reassigning caps lock to a different modifier would functionally serve the same purpose as remapping to ctrl+shift.

Comment: @xiota Sure, I can go thru dozens of applications, but some of them doesn't allow keybinding remappings - Slack is such an example. Besides it is a bigger effort, and not the solution for the question.

Comment: From some reading ([e.g.](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/possible-to-xmodmap-two-keys-at-same-time-459410/), [e.g.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251479/how-to-bind-ctrlarrows-to-home-and-end-keys-xmodmap-does-not-work/303978#303978)), it seems this is not possible with `xmodmap`. Sounds like you'll have to have a service running in the background to do it.